# Is it impossible to return a reference to a const pointer to const data?

Tags: c++

I am having some problems trying to return a **reference** to a const pointer to **const** data. In the following code, get_pC returns a reference to a const pointer to data:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class C {
public:
    double c;
};

class A {
public:
    C* pC;
    A(const double val):pC(new C){pC->c=val;};
};

class B {
public:
    const A* pA;
    B(const A& a):pA(&a){}; 
    C * const & get_pC() const { return pA->pC; }
};

int main() {
    A a(3.7);
    B b(a);
    C * const & r = b.get_pC();
    r->c=2.2;
    cout<<(long) &b.pA->pC<<endl;
    cout<<(long) &r<<endl;
}
```

By compiling this code, there is no error shown so it is allowed to modify "c" through "r". That's ok. Moreover, the address of b.pA->pC matches the address of r. That is nice too ^_^

But, when I try to disallow the modification of "c" through "r" is when I experience problems. If I add const to the declaration of "r":

```
const C * const & r = b.get_pC();
```

then the compiler complains about the modification of "c". Perfect, that's exactly what I want... right? Unfortunately no, now the addresses of "r" and b.pA->pC are different!!!

Is it impossible to do what I am trying to do? I know that it would be possible to do something "similar" by returning a pointer instead of a reference:

```
const C * const * get_pC() const { return &pA->pC; }
const C * const * r = b.get_pC();
```

but it would add one level of indirection and I am curious to know if it is really impossible or there is a way to make it work with references.

Comment: Under the hood your cmpiler *most likely* model pointers and references *the exact same way*, so performance/extra indirection is unlikely to be a valid argument for code passing through an optimizing compiler.

Comment: Works if you use const_cast. Otherwise, usual rules, binding X with Y const& creates a temporary of type Y if X and Y are different.

Comment: Perhaps, since there is no actual `const C` to point to, `r` binds to a temporary value that is the result of the implicit conversion of `b.get_pC();` to `const C*`?

Comment: @Marc Glisse - eeew, `const_cast`; instant code smell.

Comment: _"return a reference to a const pointer to const data"_ -- Why? Just return the pointer *by value*.

Comment: @JesperJuhl bit it's actually a const_cast adding const-ness. Would be bad if immutability is expected

Comment: I applied described changes to your code-snippet and... I see equal addresses. Please, provide final code that I can copy\paste and reproduce your problem.

Comment: @MarcGlisse re. your first comment: there are some more cases where X and Y are different but there is no temporary. Namely, if Y is a base class of X, and/or Y has extra top-level cv-qualifiers. The term used by the standard is *not reference-related* rather than *different*

Comment: @JesperJuhl the complaint about extra indirection is not about performance but more about a cascade of changes in the real code. Sorry for not making it sufficiently clear.

Comment: @MarcGlisse thanks, I have never used const_cast and it seems that it is the only option.

Comment: @zett42 I want "r" to be an alias of "b.pA->pC" not a copy because if "b.pA->pC" is changed I want "r" to react to that change.

Comment: @PavloK you can find it here: [link] (https://onlinegdb.com/S13dIuFDG)

Comment: Thanks. It seems that VC++ works in a different way. I just tested it here [here](http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_visual). CLang and GCC shows issue that you mentioned. Bug VC++ works as you (and me) expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simpler version of the "problem" would be:

```
int x;
int *p = &x;

int*       const& r1 = p;
const int* const& r2 = p;
```

In this case `r1` binds directly to `p`, so `&r1 == &p`.  However, `r2` cannot bind directly to `p`. Instead, the `r2` line creates a temporary `const int *` object and binds `r2` to the temporary.

This is always a possibility when using const lvalue references;  if the type is not right for direct binding, but an implicit conversion exists, then a temporary may be created.

To avoid the temporary you would need to use a cast:

```
const int* const & r2 = const_cast<const int* &>(p);
```

or in your original code:

```
const C * const & r = const_cast<const C * &>(b.get_pC());
```

*Remark:* It's considered poor style to store the address of something that was passed by reference (because the caller does not expect this to happen and the object may end its lifetime). Consider redesigning your code rather than actually using this `const_cast` solution; e.g. use `C * const * get_pC() const { return &pA->pC; }` and `const C * const * r = b.get_pC();`

---

To summarize the relevant reference binding rule: references only bind directly if the two types are the same, (or a base class reference can bind to derived class), with the left-hand side type possibly having extra top-level qualifiers. [See here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization) for more detail, or [dcl.init.ref] section of the Standard.

Comment: Using vs2017 I can see that both r1 and r2 properly (equaly) refer to x (p) objects. What make you think that there are any extra locals created?

Comment: @PavloK Because I know the rules of reference initialization as set out in the C++ Standard. Maybe you found a bug in VS2017. See N4659 11.6.3/5.2.2.2 "Otherwise, the initializer expression is implicitly converted to a prvalue of type “cv1 T1 ”. The temporary materialization conversion is applied and the reference is bound to the result."

Comment: Could you please provide reference to this part of standard? Because per my feeling of beauty implicit creating locals for references doesn't sound logical.

Comment: @PavloK My previous comment has a reference to the standard, and I put a cppreference.com link into my answer.  Some more familiar examples of const lvalue reference binding creating a temporary would be `const int &x = 5;`, or `const std::string & s  = "hello";`. This is why you can pass C string literals to functions that accept `const std::string&`

Comment: Well, your explanation and examples makes sense... Thank you. What compiler do you use btw?

Comment: @M.M thank you, I see now that const_cast is the solution for this problem. I have never used const_cast before and when I tried to use it to solve this problem I did this:
`const C * const & get_pC() const { return const_cast<const C*> (pA->pC); }`
and of course it didn't work because I forgot to specify that it had to be a reference. Sorry for making the code in the question more complicated than it was necessary :S

Comment: @M.M @M.M about the remark: I am not sure to fully understand it. For example: `int** ppa=new int*; const int * const & r=const_cast<const int*&> (*ppa); const int * const * r2= &(*ppa); cout<<(long) ppa<<endl; cout<<(long) &r<<endl; cout<<(long) r2<<endl;  delete ppa; cout<<(long) ppa<<endl; cout<<(long) &r<<endl; cout<<(long) r2<<endl;` 

Sorry, I don't know how to format code in comments :S : [link](https://onlinegdb.com/ByJ1GtFPz)

I think that in this case `r` and `r2` are in a similar bad situation after `delete ppa`.

Comment: @Jorge doing `&r` after `delete ppa;` causes undefined behaviour. Also, trying to output `ppa` or `r2` after `delete ppa;` causes implementation-defined behaviour since C++14 (was undefined behaviour prior to that), which might generate a runtime fault. This is something you should avoid doing

Comment: @M.M that's my point and the target of the example code in the comment. At the end of your remark, it is recommended to use a pointer, like `r2`, instead of using const_cast with a reference, like `r`, but I think that both are in a very similar bad situation when the lifetime of the real object ends. To summarize it, I think that there must be a different reason to choose one solution over the other.

Comment: @Jorge You haven't mentioned `delete`-ing anything until now; this doesn't have anything to do with your question as written. In no case should you delete a pointer and then try to keep using the address of the deleted object.  If you don't know whether or not your pointer was deleted then you need to redesign your code.

Comment: @M.M in the **_Remark_** you mentioned _"the object may end its lifetime"_ and, if I understood correctly, that was a reason why you recommended to redesign the code by using a pointer instead of a reference with const_cast. My point is that both options are bad if _"the object may end its lifetime"_. That's why I introduced `delete` in the example, to show that it is bad for the reference with const_cast and bad for the pointer, both situations should be avoided, and that there must be a different reason to prefer one over the other.

Comment: @Jorge The idea is that using a pointer reminds the caller not to end the lifetime because the function might have retained a copy of the pointer

Answer (score 3):

> Unfortunately no, now the addresses of `r` and `b.pA->pC` are different!!!

My guess is that in the process of converting `C * const &` to `C const* const &`, the compiler creates a temporary of type `C const*` and `r` is a reference to that. It's as if you are using:

```
C const* temp = b.get_pC();
C const* const& r = temp;
```